# ¿Cómo trasponer columnas por filas en un archivo CSV, delimitando cada fila por ";"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, procesamiento-de-texto, cut

Tengo un archivo CSV sobre el covid19 y necesito pasar la primera columna a una fila delimitada por ";", la cual tengo que imprimir por pantalla de la Shell.

Cada valor no puede estar repetido pero esto ya lo he conseguido, solo me falta trasponer.

Pongo el código que he hecho hasta ahora:

```
cat covid19.csv | sort | cut -d "," -f1 | uniq
```

He visto que para trasponer se podría utilizar sed y awk pero no lo tengo permitido. Tengo que apañármelas para buscar otra manera. Pensé que igual podría utilizar un bucle for para ello ya que lo vi en un foro pero por ahora no consigo hacerlo así.

Comment: Puede que no haya quedado claro en el enunciado, perdón. Necesito imprimir dicha fila por pantalla. O sea, yo lo que tengo es un archivo CSV de X columnas (no recuerdo ahora cuántas tiene) en donde me piden imprimir por pantalla de la shell la primera columna traspuesta a fila y delimitada por " ; ".

Comment: es decir que quieres imprimir una columna específica y ya está. `cut` es una muy buena manera de hacerlo, ¿no te funcionó?

Comment: Sí, exacto, pero en forma de fila. Cut me devuelve la columna tal cual. La salida debe ser en forma fila y cada valor separado por punto y coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ibas bien con `cut` para conseguir la primera columna. Ahora se trata de juntar todas las líneas y esto se puede hacer con `tr` que traduce (`tr`aduce) un carácter en otro; en este caso, el salto de línea en punto y coma:

```
cut -d',' -f1 fichero.csv | tr '\n' ';'
```

La parte de `uniq` puedes ponerla tras `cut` si te es necesaria.

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
hola,que,tal
esto,es,una,cancion
bastante,simple
pero,que,a,mi,me,gusta
un,saludo,cordial

$ cut -d',' -f1 fichero | tr '\n' ','
hola;esto;bastante;pero;un;
```

Fíjate que siempre queda un `;` final, pues la última línea también tiene un salto de línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha funcionado! Lo que me faltaba era el comando `tr`. Aún no sé muy bien la funcionalidad de este, sé que puede sustituir caracteres por otros pero poco más, así que buscaré sus posibles usos por si me sirve de cara al futuro. Saludos!!

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguezPardo `tr` sirve para "tr"aducir. Por ejemplo, en ` tr 'a' 'b' <<< "abc"` cambia las "a" por "b" y en `tr '[1-9]' 'b' <<< "abc123"` cambia los dígitos por una "b". También tiene funcionalidades útiles como `tr -s` para eliminar múltiples ocurrencias de un carácter (por ejemplo para cambiar muchos espacios a uno solo)

Comment: Genial! Muchísimas gracias por la información y por la ayuda!!!